# Measure Theory/Numerical Analysis help!

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f (x) = (x − 1)^{10}, p = 1$, and $p_n = 1 + 1/n$. Show that $ |f ( p_n)| < 10^{-3}$ whenever $n > 1$ but that $ | p − p_n| < 10^{−3}$ requires that $n > 1000$.

I really don't know how to start solving this. Any help would be appreciated to get me started.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:$$|f ( p_n)|=(\frac{1}{n})^{10}<\frac{1}{2^{10}-24}=10^{-3}$$
$$| p − p_n|=\frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I ended up being able to finish the problem.